# Custom Product Filter GraphQl Not working in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, graphql

I want to add a stock filter for the product search GraphQl query. check below my code

> schema.graphqls

```
input ProductAttributeFilterInput @doc(description: "Defines the filters"){
    stock_status: FilterEqualTypeInput
}
```

> di.xml

```
   <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\ProductFilterProcessor" type="Magento\Eav\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="customFilters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="stock_status" xsi:type="object">Custom\Module\Model\Resolver\Products\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\CustomStockFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

> CustomStockFilter.php

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Model\Resolver\Products\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\CustomFilterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;

class CustomStockFilter implements CustomFilterInterface
{

    private $logger;
    private $stock;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stock
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->stock = $stock;
    }


    /**
     * Apply filter by 'category_id' to product collection.
     *
     * For anchor categories, the products from all children categories will be present in the result.
     *
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param AbstractDb $collection
     * @return bool Whether the filter is applied
     */
    public function apply(Filter $filter, AbstractDb $collection)
    {
        $this->logger->info('stock filter log');
        $conditionType = $filter->getConditionType();
        $value = $filter->getValue();
        $this->stock->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

GraphQL Query

```
{
  products(
    search: "test"
    filter: { stock_status: { in: ["1"] } }
  ) {
    items {
      uid
    }
  }
}
```

I added a logger in the resolver file but the resolver is not triggered. my Magento ver. 2.4.4-p1.

how to add in-stock/outstock filter in product search query.

**stock_status** I added a custom field but its not working

please help me on this

Comment: For now Igonre file trigger or not but just confirm as per your attribute value products data returns or not? Like this image: https://prnt.sc/Vc6iTdsFpN1M

Comment: no its not return

Comment: Have you created attributes by admin or script?

Comment: by admin added the attributes

Comment: So you need to configure attribute like this: https://prnt.sc/mw6vZWkXLb11

Comment: if its a text field thenn its wont work